# Which lifecycle called when i am press the back button in fragment

Tags: android, fragment, back

I am using action bar in my application with three action bar tab.The    second action bar tab having two fragment(A and B).
          When i click the A fragment list item it redirect into B fragment and then press the back button from B fragment to A fragment    at which life cycle is invoked in A Fragment.
          let me know thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK,All backPress events will be received by your fragment Activity , as fragments are just child of it.
Put a log in it and just check the result in logcat.

You can find answer of this kind of questions by trial and error, you will also learn a lot by this kind of methodologies.

Comment: ya it is nice method to find out whole lifecycle scenario.